# Which interrupts are enabled when programming an ATTiny85 with Arduino IDE?

Tags: arduino-ide, attiny

I have programmed a tiny85 using the Arduino IDE. I am using the pulseIn() function. Wrapping it in noInterrupts()/interrupts(); appears to make the function more consistent. This would imply that interrupts are running.

Which interrupts are running? Can I disable them?

I am using the analogWrite() function to pins that have PWM support. Disabling the interrupts for a "long" time does not seam to effect these, this implies the PWMs are producing the analogue signal in hardware and so interrupts are not required.

(I know I can improve the code by not using pulseIn and using interrupts, however the question I have at the moment is which interrupts are running when I am not explicitly enabling any.)

Comment: It could depend on the arduino core you're using for the ATTiny. As there are multiple, and there is not one present in the default IDE (afaik).

Answer (score 1):

The only interrupt that is *always* running is the one which generates the count for `millis()` and `micros()`. Disabling interrupts disables your ability to keep track of time and use `delay()`.

Timer interrupts are also used by the `tone()` function and for sending / receiving serial data if the chip has a UART.

Disabling interrupts would also affect the use of external interrupts and pin change interrupts should you be using them.

It sounds, from your brief description, that you would only be effecting the use of `millis()` and `delay()` since you aren't using the other systems that use interrupts at all.

Comment: After more reading it states that the pulseIn() requires interrupts, this is a bit strange. I would not expect to see an "improvement" doing what I am doing. Perhaps the tiny85 implementation is different than the standard one. If timing is available I would expect pulseIn to use it, as the description implies, and therefore require interrupts to be enabled. What you describe makes a lot of sense, I will recheck my findings.

Comment: `pulseIn()` function has got a very high accuracy, to the level of us (microseconds), which `millis()` function has obviously not. This is why `pulseIn` does not use it. Note that even `micros()` does not offer high precision, despite its name.

Answer (score 0):

> Which interrupts are running?

It depends on your code which you haven't shown. The Timer 0 overflow interrupt is usually active, as that lets the library count when a millisecond is up (roughly).

If you have done a `Serial.begin` then serial interrupts would be active. If you have used the I2C library (Wire) then I2C interrupts would be active.

*(Disclaimer: That really refers to the Atmega328P. I'm not quite so sure on the ATtiny, it would depend on what the libraries do).*

---

> Can I disable them?

If you want to. Doing `noInterrupts()` is the simplest way. Note that if you disable interrupts for more than a millisecond (approximately) then the time returned by `millis` and `micros` will be wrong. Plus `delay` won't work. Plus you won't be able to serial print properly or at all.

---

> I am using the analogWrite() function to pins that have PWM support. Disabling the interrupts for a "long" time does not seam to effect these, this implies the PWMs are producing the analogue signal in hardware and so interrupts are not required.

That is exactly what it does. Once activated the hardware timers can generate a PWM signal purely in hardware.

---

There are other ways of timing intervals (than `pulseIn`). One method is to use one of the other timers, configured with a small, or no prescaler. Then you can measure up to very high accuracy. I have examples of that on [my page about timers](http://www.gammon.com.au/timers).

*(The ATtiny85 only has two timers, so you couldn't use the second timer for measuring **and** do PWM output with it, however you can use Timer 0 for the PWM output). That limits the PWM frequency to its default, however you could still alter the duty cycle)*